# TypeError: Cannot read property 'isSkipSelf' of null Angular 6

Tags: angular

I've created a library with Angular 6 and built it succesfully.
Once I add a module(**AdjudicationHistoriqueModule**) to my library module, I get the following error when i build the library:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'isSkipSelf' of null
    at ProviderElementContext._getDependency (C:\Users\taha.manar\Documents\workspace\ADJUDICATION-IHM\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:11483:22)
    at C:\Users\taha.manar\Documents\workspace\ADJUDICATION-IHM\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:11428:64
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Users\taha.manar\Documents\workspace\ADJUDICATION-IHM\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:11428:30
...
```

I also get the same error when adding the line below to the pulic_api.ts file

```
export * from './lib/historique/adjudication-historique.module';
```

adjudication-historique.module.ts

```
import { AlmCommonModule } from './../Common/alm-common.module';
import { AlmRootPageModule } from './../Common/root-page/root-page.module';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { AdjudicationHistoriqueRoutingModule } from './adjudication-historique-routing.module';
import { HistoriqueComponent } from './historique.component';
import { AdjudicationStructHistoriqueComponent } from './adjudication-struct-historique.component';
import { HistoriqueService } from './historique.service';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
CommonModule,AdjudicationHistoriqueRoutingModule,AlmRootPageModule,AlmCommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [HistoriqueComponent,AdjudicationStructHistoriqueComponent]
,
providers : [HistoriqueService]

})
export class AdjudicationHistoriqueModule { }
```

adjudication.module.ts (Library module)

```
import { HistoriqueService } from './historique/historique.service';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AdjudicationComponent } from './adjudication.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
  ],
  declarations: [AdjudicationComponent],
  exports: [AdjudicationComponent],
  providers: [HistoriqueService]
})
export class AdjudicationModule { }
```

P.S : I'm upgrading my project from Angular 4 to Angular 6

Comment: this could help https://github.com/angular/vscode-ng-language-service/issues/181